# Does doClick() require a component to be enabled?

Tags: java, swing

I understand that `doClick()` simulates a user effectively clicking a button (or other component). Does this require the button to be enabled (not greyed out, clickable, etc.)? Can I assume that `doClick()` just calls the action listener and perhaps does some animation from the button?

Comment: Just did. Didn't see a question on this topic, so I thought I would add to the pool of answers if I found out. Plus, I'm not a Java expert, and was optimistically hoping for a detailed explanation on how it works. (did a search on the mechanics, didn't find too much)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen and played with, doClick() does not require the button to be enabled or otherwise "clickable".

Comment: For the record, `doClick()` calls the button model's `setPressed()` twice; the default implementation for the model (`DefaultButtonModel.setPressed()`) checks the enabled state before firing the action event.